# react redirect fires irrespective of the condition

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
 <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICE_VALIDATION}>
            {perm ? <PriceValidation/> :  <Redirect to={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICEZONE_REASSIGNMENT}/> }
 </Route>
```

I have the above set up where upon a condition I want to direct the route to a different component. but eventhough the perm condition becomes true I am still being redirected to reassignment tab. what am i doing wrong here ?

full code

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Redirect, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {notification} from 'antd';
import Login from './Login/Login';
import PriceValidation from './PriceValidation/PriceValidation';
import FileUpload from './FileUpload/FileUpload';
import PZRHome from './PriceZoneReassignment/PZRHome';
import {auth} from '../utils/security/Auth';
import AppLoader from '../components/AppLoader';
import {UserDetailContext} from './UserDetailContext';
import {AppLoaderContext} from '../components/AppLoderContext';
import {
 NAVIGATION_PATH_FILE_UPLOAD,
 NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICE_VALIDATION,
 SUPPORTED_WEB_BROWSERS,
 NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICEZONE_REASSIGNMENT, SCREEN_PRICE_VALIDATION
} from '../constants/Constants';
    import {grantViewPermissionsToScreens, unsupportedBrowserState}    from '../utils/CommonUtils';
   import UnsupportedBrowserScreen from '../components/UnsupportedBrowser/UnsupportedBrowserScreen';
   import BrowserDetector from '../utils/BrowserDetector';
   import NetworkConnectivityAlert from '../components/NetworkConnectivityAlert/NetworkConnectivityAlert';
   import UnsupportedBrowserTopAlert from '../components/UnsupportedBrowser/UnsupportedBrowserTopAlert';

const Application = (user, perm, perm1) => {
    console.log('.perms...')
    console.log(perm)
    console.log(perm1)
    return(
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_FILE_UPLOAD}>
                <FileUpload/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICE_VALIDATION}>
                {perm ? <PriceValidation/> :  <Redirect to={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICEZONE_REASSIGNMENT}/> }
            </Route>
            <Route exact path={NAVIGATION_PATH_PRICEZONE_REASSIGNMENT}>
                <PZRHome/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default function ApplicationBase() {
    const userDetailContext = useContext(UserDetailContext);
    const appLoaderContext = useContext(AppLoaderContext);
    const browserDetector = new BrowserDetector(SUPPORTED_WEB_BROWSERS);

// prevent dragover and drop events in the window
window.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
window.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

// Global configurations for notifications
notification.config({
    placement: 'bottomRight',
    duration: 3,
});

useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.isUserLoginPending() || auth.shouldFetchUserDetailsAgain(userDetailContext)) {
        if (appLoaderContext.appLoadingState !== true) {
            appLoaderContext.setAppLoadingState(true);
        } else {
            auth.userDetailContextHandler(userDetailContext, appLoaderContext);
        }
    }
});

let component;

if (!browserDetector.isSupported() && !unsupportedBrowserState.isSetUnsupportedBrowserScreenContinue()) {
    component = <UnsupportedBrowserScreen
        browserName={browserDetector.getBrowserName()}
        browserVersion={browserDetector.getBrowserVersion()}
        fullBrowserVersion={browserDetector.getFullBrowserVersion()}/>;
} else if (appLoaderContext.appLoadingState) {
    component = <AppLoader/>;
} else {

    const userRole = userDetailContext?.userDetailsData?.userDetails?.role;
    const perm = grantViewPermissionsToScreens(userRole,SCREEN_PRICE_VALIDATION);
    console.log('.......perm.......');
    console.log(perm);
    console.log('.......! perm.......');
    console.log(!perm);
    component = auth.isUserLoginCompleted() ? Application(userRole,perm,!perm) : <Login/>;
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <NetworkConnectivityAlert/>
        <UnsupportedBrowserTopAlert/>
        {component}
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

}

Comment: Based on just those 3 lines of code that should work. We're gonna need more context. What is `perm`, how is it changing, etc.

Comment: @Jayce444 i have added the full code here

Comment: Hmm ok it looks like `grantViewPermissionsToScreens` determines what `perm` is. Is there any asynchronous code in there? I'm guessing this issue is because the conditional rendering is based on some value that is set asynchronously, so the rendering completes before it can be set, by which time you've already redirected the user